# Which package the YangInferencePipeline in yang parser library has moved to?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, yang

I upgraded my opendaylight yangtools libraries to 6.0.3 and the code breaks with the below errror(s):

```
import org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.stmt.rfc6020.YangInferencePipeline;
The import cannot be resolved
```

I am not sure to which package/module the YangInferencePipeline has moved? It is used in code to build the `schemaContext`

```
CrossSourceStatementReactor.BuildAction reactor = YangInferencePipeline.RFC6020_REACTOR.newBuild();
```

What should be the `rfc7950` equivalent invocation for it in the updated libraries? Have already looked up the Javadoc at https://javadoc.io/doc/org.opendaylight.yangtools/yangtools-docs/latest/org/opendaylight/yangtools/yang/parser/rfc7950/stmt/package-summary.html but cannot locate the class.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is latest model 7.0.14 version. make sure you have updated pom.xml

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
   <artifactId>yang-parser-impl</artifactId>
   <version>${opendaylight.yangtools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
   <artifactId>yang-model-util</artifactId>
   <version>${opendaylight.yangtools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code Changes**

```
String folderPath - yang file location
List<String> files - yang files retrived list

final CustomCrossSourceStatementReactorBuilder builder = RFC7950Reactors.defaultReactorBuilder();
final BuildAction buildAction = builder.build().newBuild();

for (final String fileName : files) {
    final File file = new File(folderPath.concat("" + File.separatorChar).concat(fileName));
    buildAction.addSource(YangStatementStreamSource.create(YangTextSchemaSource.forFile(file)));
}
final SchemaContext schemaContext = buildAction.buildEffective();
Collection<? extends Module> yangModules = schemaContext.getModules();
```

Answer (score 1):

[This commit](https://github.com/opendaylight/yangtools/commit/d524f6397af825eb81784cc60c776e7fcc455382) and [this commit](https://github.com/opendaylight/yangtools/commit/043b7275acc4712d396606005a921415527135c0#diff-05de6161fb2465a25a819e308f6bf5cea81729b3a038c9738f7393a2b1082730) eliminates `org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.parser.stmt.rfc6020`. Use `DefaultReactors.defaultReactor().newBuild()` instead.

Comment: Let me try that out!

Comment: I tried my luck with the changes and it seems that it is going to be a complete overwrite of all the existing packages